# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple and then Combine Data to one Plot

Tags: python, arrays, plot

I am getting a "TypeError" for my main code so I made a small code to try and reproduce the problem. I was able to reproduce the error, but I am not sure what is wrong. I tried converting my arrays to integers, but that didn't work. Here is the small code that I have been working with to try and correct the error.

```
x = [5,10,15,20,25]
y = [9,10,20,15,25]
x0 = np.linspace(0,3)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=3, nrows=4, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(7,7))

for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
    ax.scatter(x[:,i], y[:,i], s=10)
    m, b = np.polyfit(x[:,i], y[:,i], 1)
    ax.plot(x0, m*x0+b, lw=1., label="y={:.2f}x+{:.2f}".format(m,b))
    ax.legend()

plt.tight_layout()    
plt.show()
```

How do I convert the arrays' indices to integers, so that they aren't tuple? I would like all the same data to stay the same. If you need to you can extend the arrays out and make them longer to show me exactly what the problem is.

After this, I would like to combine all the data from the plots onto one plot so that I can see all the linear regression lines and points all plotted on the same graph.

Comment: With e.g. `x[:,i]` you're indexing it as it it was a numpy array, but it's just a regular list.

Comment: Should I index a regular list, or should I change the code to something else.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you're trying to achieve. If you just want to plot `x` against `y`, I don't think you need to index them at all.

Comment: Basically, I want the code to produce multiple plots without me having to copy and paste code, and then at the end I want to combine all the data and linear regression lines from all the plots onto one plot. My main code has two really long lists; I have used short ones here.

Comment: Actually, I might have figured out the problem. Thanks!

Comment: If you no longer have a problem, I'd suggest deleting the question. Glad you sorted it!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
x = [5,10,15,20,25]
y = [9,10,20,15,25]
x0 = np.linspace(0,3)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=3, nrows=4, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(7,7))

for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
    ax.scatter(np.array(x[:i]), np.array(y[:i]), 10)
    m, b = np.polyfit(np.array(x[:i+1]), np.array(y[:i+1]), 1)
    ax.plot(x0, m*x0+b, lw=1., label="y={:.2f}x+{:.2f}".format(m,b))
    ax.legend()

plt.tight_layout()    
plt.show()
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error when I copy and pasted your code to mine.

Comment: I just checked and this seems to work! I just have to try it in my main code now.